# Should Javascript scrollIntoView() vary on different browsers?

Tags: javascript

[HTML & Javascript example](https://julianlocals.com/cwhii/so/220716_so.html#Moe) with a hash tag in the URL. The script will  locate an element with text of the value of the hash tag as there is no element with the corresponding ID attribute then scoll to that element. This works on Firefox.

Is there a reason it should not work on Chrome?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr"><head><meta charset="UTF-8"><title>SO URL Hash Shim Example</title>
<script>
if (bare_hash = window.location.hash?.substring(1)){
    window.onload = function(){  
        function get_element_by_content (bare_hash_a, tag_a){
            return Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName(tag_a)).find(e_a=>e_a.innerText.includes(bare_hash_a));
            }
        get_element_by_content(bare_hash, "h1")?.parentNode.scrollIntoView();
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- 1 -->
    <div>
        <img src="https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/so/logo-stackoverflow.svg" alt='SO'>
        <h1>Bob</h1>
        <hr>
        </div>
<!-- 2 -->
    <div>
        <img src="https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/so/logo-stackoverflow.svg" alt='SO'>
        <h1>Larry</h1>
        <hr>
        </div>
<!-- ... -->
<!-- 9  -->
    <div>
        <img src="https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/so/logo-stackoverflow.svg" alt='SO'>
        <h1>Steve</h1>
        <hr>
        </div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: It works for me in Chrome if I change `#Moe` to `#Steve`. It scrolls Steve into view.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView Support is shown below! For IE and Safari you'll need to implement support or change the function up a bit.